# Best way to define the values for a column in a database

Tags: database-design, data-structures

This is a very exploratory question. Suppose we are designing a database for a University; this place has semesters as the basic educational time unit. There are 2 semesters in a year with one half-semester in the summer. They are called terms as a way of describing them. If we want to designate an integer for a term at a point of time (say Autumn 2012 or Spring 2013 or Summer 2013) what do you say is the best composite integer?

For example, would it be 20121 for Spring 2012 where the last digit is the term?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, as I see you tagged this question as `database-design` I have to argue on assigning an integer to two values: Year and Season. You can't have a table in [First Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) if you have multivaluated fields.

This will bring you complications when you try to run a query for one of those fields. You won't be able to EASILY answer simple queries like 'How many different years do you have?' without parsing the data. So my advise would be to split the integer you're talking about into fields `Year` and `Season`.

Now, if you insist on using an integer to store both values... then your solution seems to be perfect :)

Comment: The main reason to denormalize the term is because of simple queries such as "give me the courses that have been taught by this professor since Summer 2006." Since the term is an integer, you can conduct math on it to get results.

Comment: You can do the same with a normalized table, but you will also have more flexibility. I mean you can do whatever you do with the denormalized solution but in a simpler way. Why would you "conduct math" when you don't need to? That's unnecesary processing and should (must?) be avoided

Comment: @sunbomb: "since Summer 2006" can be treated in some DBMS with the simple `WHERE (yearColumn, semesterColumn) >= (2006, 2)`

Comment: This might be out-of-topic, but why is it that PeopleSoft Student Information Systems (the main Univ system here) uses a similar column for it's term? Here that column is called strm for any of you PS experts out there.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will apply %100 to your circumstances, but I work for a college and have run into this already.  If your University's school year starts in Fall, then you're in luck because Fall, Spring, and Summer are already naturally in time and alphabetical sequence if sorted ascendingly.  If I need a sortable composite, I use a computed field that concatenates the year and semester together.

This is what I'd suggest:

```
YearSemester:
-------------
YearSemesterID (PK and autonumbering)
Year
Semester
YearSemester (formula Year + Semester, possibly indexed if your DB supports that)
```

If you really need a number, then you could get rid of the YearSemester field, add a Sequence field, and set up a trigger that would do the Year + Semester concatenation and assign sequence numbers accordingly on each insert/update/delete.